# При сохранении XML файла посредством DOM генерируется много пустых строк

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
public static void  Save(Document SourceDocument, String NameFileXML) throws TransformerException {

        TransformerFactory factoryTrans = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            Transformer transformer = factoryTrans.newTransformer();
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(SourceDocument);
            StreamResult streamFile = new StreamResult(new 
            File(NameFileXML));
        //  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.transform(domSource, streamFile);

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

После долгих мучений выяснил что влияет приведенная ниже строка кода:

----> // **transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");**

Вывод с закоментированной строкой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Journals><Journal title="Хакер"/><Journal title="Игромания"/></Journals>
```

Вывод с незакоментированной строкой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Journals>


    <Journal title="Игромания"/>

    <Journal title="Хакер"/>
</Journals>
```

Почему появляются пустые строки в результирующем файле и как этого избежать?